# Azure blob storage download file from browser with http compression header

Tags: azure-blob-storage

does azure blob storage supports HTTP compression, so that data between storage and client browser can be compressed.
Currently my service is generating uncompressed data on blob storage and then a separate process compresses the data. I am looking for any out of box option from storage to compress data.

also can i download a folder(with multiple files) from browser, or each file has to be downloaded separately in browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for any out of box option from storage to compress data.

Unfortunately, there is none. This is something you would need to do it yourself. Also, when you compress the data, please set the `Content-Encoding` property of the blob properly (e.g. `gzip`) so that the user agent understands that the content is compressed.

> also can i download a folder(with multiple files) from browser, or
> each file has to be downloaded separately in browser?

You will need to download each blob in a folder separately.